# How to list recently deleted pages by Wikipedia API?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I am using the Wikipedia API to retrieve the latest version of Wikipedia content. I also want to call the API separately and only retrieve a list of recently deleted pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list the last 50 deleted pages in the main namespace see [deletedrevs](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bdeletedrevs):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=deletedrevs&drlimit=50&drunique=
```

To list the last 50 deleted revisions in the main namespace see [alldeletedrevisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Balldeletedrevisions):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=alldeletedrevisions&adrlimit=50
```

But in both cases you will need administrator rights.